# rspec spec automatic logical grouping (by "tags")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, components, rspec

Is there any existing solution (a gem preferably) to run some slices of specs with rspec?

for example:


`rspec . # runs whole test suite

rspec . --keywords=project # runs all specs that have "project" keyword there somewhere`

or something similar?

Answer (score 9):

You can use tags in rspec by supplying a key-value pair to a describe, context or test, like so:

```
describe "A set of tests", :constraint => 'slow'
describe "Another set of tests", :focus => true
```

You could run either of these sets by doing:

```
rspec --tag constraint:slow
rspec --tag focus
```

Comment: This is a good comment, but I am thinking more on something like grepping all spec contents and running only specs that contain my keyword

Comment: You can't do that with rspec, but you could use bash :-)

find . -type f -name '*spec' -exec grep 'search-string' {} \ | xargs rspec

Answer (score 4):

I think the built-in "--example" option does what you want:

```
rspec . --example "project"
```